# Multi-region Cloud Storage charges

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've read a few similar posts but haven't really understood why I am getting charged.

I recently (middle of May) switched from Python 2.7 environment with webapp2 to Python 3 with Flask.  I switched from using old ndb to the new ndb.  I am using Standard (not Flex)  This application has very limited use and I thought was limited to a single region. The project size is 176.3 KB

At the end of the May the following was added to my bill:

> Standard Storage US Multi-region  0D5D-6E23-4250  0.33
> gibibyte month

I'm wondering why I have 'multi-region' anything. I thought I was set up for a single region.  I never got billed for anything using Python 2.7 and webapp2 with old ndb. This application is small with limited use.  When I delete the region bucket it just comes back when a new version is deployed. I thought there was a 5GB free use limit?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the buckets in the Console Storage browser? When you create an app sometimes is created as well a bucket named `multiregionName.artifacts.projectID.appspot.com`. This bucket is Multi-region. You can check whether this bucket was created with the new versions you upgraded. If you check in the overview of the Bucket you can get the `Creation time`, `Location-type` and `Location`.

Also, according to [GAE Default Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Default_Gcs_Bucket):

> The Default Cloud Storage bucket has a free quota for daily usage as shown below. You create this free default bucket in the Google Cloud Console App Engine settings page for your project.
>
> The following quotas apply specifically to use of the default bucket. See [pricing for Cloud Storage Multi-Regional buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) for a description of these quotas.

In a nutshell, I would check the content of the multiregional bucket. If it has something investigate the actual usage and decide either to delete something or not.

Otherwise just calculate the estimated cost according to the [pricing table](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#price-tables) and verify that is correct.

**UPDATE**

I created an GAE App and it created the following buckets:

- `joss-xxx.appspot.com`
- `staging.joss-xxx.appspot.com`   Multiregion
- `us.artifacts.joss-xxx.appspot.com`    Multi-region

I tested deleting the buckets as you did and each time I deploy I get those three buckets again. So here the explanation:

joss-xxx.appspot.com is the default bucket for GAE, and has a 5GB free storage quota and is provided for your usage.

About the staging Bucket I found [this (1)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-cloud-storage) and [this (2)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#activating_a_cloud_storage_bucket) which mentions:

> 1. Note: When you create a default bucket, you also get a staging bucket with the same name except that staging. is prepended to it. You can use this staging bucket for temporary files used for staging and test purposes; it also has a 5 GB limit, but it is automatically emptied on a weekly basis.

> 2. App Engine also creates a bucket that it uses for temporary storage when it deploys new versions of your app. This bucket, named staging.project-id.appspot.com, is for use by App Engine only. Apps can't interact with this bucket.

The `artifacts` bucket, `{region}.artifacts.{app-id}.appspot.com` is used to build the docker container that GAE Flexible deploys. Even when I deployed an Standard app, this bucket was created. Deleting this bucket will likely increase your deploy times as the new deployment cannot build on your previous deployment.

Given the aforementioned, I think the behavior you are facing is totally expected.

Comment: As I said in the post, 'When I delete the region bucket it just comes back when a new version is deployed' 
And I'm in us-east1 which says: Cloud Storage Always Free quotas apply to usage in US-WEST1, US-CENTRAL1, and US-EAST1 regions. 
And no matter what --bucket I use on upload it recreates the mult-region bucket.

Comment: The SKU is related to the MultiRegion Bucket. Have you tried deleting it?

Comment: Maybe you are confused by my wording so I'll say it again slightly different. When I delete the multi-region bucket it just comes back when a new version is deployed'.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not expected to generate a multi-region artifact for a product that is is created in a single region data center. Google asks the customer to choose either a single region (free) or a multi-region (not free) data center to host their data, customer chooses the single region and then customer gets charged because Google creates a multi-region artifact.  I've been discussing this issue with google since the day I posted this and they still can't tell me why I am getting charged.

Comment: I wrote about this unwanted behavior here. Unfortunately I have not found a solution yet. https://amiaudible.medium.com/google-cloud-app-engine-forced-charges-8b2efc06f137?source=friends_link&sk=5d32a73fa6067a31256f920b2807d936

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same behavior for my app, I'm not sure if you have reached to any conclusion since you posted this question.

I deployed an app in an specific region but Google creates multi-region buckets automatically, in my case two of them are "multi-region" at least in the same region I stated, but for the artifact, I get a "multi-region" bucket in a completely different region, which is the one I'm getting charged by. Either way I'm not going over the free quotas so I don't understand why they are charging me for.

I was thinking on trying a "[bucket move](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets)", manually recreating a single region bucket with the same name/properties and transferring the actual content to this new one, but I'm not sure if I'll break something, I'm still learning on these GCP topics.

Comment: Google was zero help.  Despite the fact that you explicitly sign up for non-multi region they will always generate this multi-region bucket whenever you upload a new version.  The only solution is to delete this bucket every time you upload. Another thing I have done is to only ever install a single version '--version v1' for example.

Comment: Deleting the bucket after deployment does not prevent incurring charges. I did that but still ended up with a significant bill for that day. I wrote about it here https://amiaudible.medium.com/google-cloud-app-engine-forced-charges-8b2efc06f137?source=friends_link&sk=5d32a73fa6067a31256f920b2807d936

Answer (score 0):

According to Google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/using-cloud-storage?tab=python)

> App Engine creates a default bucket when you create an app. This
> bucket provides the first 5GB of storage for free and includes a free
> quota for Cloud Storage I/O operations. You can create other Cloud
> Storage buckets, but only the default bucket includes the first 5GB of
> storage for free.

Also the [same page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/using-cloud-storage?tab=python#default_bucket) states

> App Engine also creates a bucket that it uses for temporary storage when it deploys new versions of your app. This bucket, named staging.project-id.appspot.com, is for use by App Engine only. Apps can't interact with this bucket.

The location of the default bucket should match the location of the app but not  [always](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/locations#cloud-storage-location). For the us-central location, the buckets are US multi-region, which are not free. The staging bucket has a rule to empty automatically after 7 days. But you will do well to double check.

However, this is not all the storage that App Engine creates.

I don't quite know how Python27 runtime did it because I have never encountered any charges while using it.

The python38 runtime is using cloud build to [build the images](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/testing-and-deploying-your-app?tab=python#managing_build_images). That uses additional storage that is not cleaned up and must be cleaned up manually if you want to avoid charges.
The container registry uses cloud storage to store images in the [following bucket](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#grant) **STORAGE-REGION.artifacts.PROJECT-ID.appspot.com**. This bucket does not have a lifecycle management and that is the one that is causing the charges.

IMHO, Google is being very sneaky with the free tier and does not clearly describe all that can cause charges on one page. The data accumulates over time and you need to pay attention to your billing page as one day you will incur charges.

To avoid charges, you can try to add [lifecycle rule](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) to delete data from the buckets every day, or write a script to deploy your app and then empty all of the relevant buckets. You can use **gcloud** or **gsutis** command to empty the buckets, right after you deploy your app. You do not need to delete buckets, just delete all objects in them.

Comment: 3 years later since this malpractice has come to life and there has been no cure. This is quite a feat Google has pulled here. I had a project running on free tier for 8yrs now. I deployed a new version 3 days back and bam!! I am getting charged money everyday now. I had to spent 3 days to understand and track down this predatory dark pattern.